# Regra de seleção de registros baseado na data e na hora

Tags: php, mysql, apache-cordova

Eu estou desenvolvendo um sistema de apostas online e ao selecionar os jogos cadastrados no sistema eu preciso selecionar somente os jogos do dia atual em diante, adicionalmente eu preciso me certificar de não selecionar os jogos que já começaram, ou seja, aqueles nos quais a hora atual seja maior que a hora do registro.

Até agora eu consigo selecionar os registros de hoje em diante por data, mas eu não consegui fazer a condição da hora. Vou deixar a query que tenho atualmente abaixo.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(timee.nome_time ORDER BY timee.nome_time SEPARATOR ' X ') AS nome_time, 
partida.id, DATE_FORMAT(partida.data_hora, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') AS data_hora, 
partida.tb_cotacao_id
FROM tb_partida AS partida, tb_time AS timee, tb_partida_time AS partidaTime 
WHERE (partida.id = tb_partida_id && timee.id = tb_time_id)
AND (partida.flag_ativo = 1 AND partida.flag_cancelado <> 1 AND partida.flag_finalizado <> 1) 
AND (date(partida.data_hora) >= date(now()) AND (TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(now(), partida.data_hora)) > 600))
AND partida.tb_campeonato_id = 11 
GROUP BY partida.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pela estrutura você está utilizando o `DATETIME` em `partida.data_hora`.

Se você usa:

```
date(partida.data_hora) >= date(now())
```

Está garantindo que o ano, mês e dia será maior e igual ao atual, mas o horário em ambos não entra na comparação, em outras palavras:

```
SELECT DATE('2017-12-31 01:02:03');
// Resultado : 2017-12-31
```

Você pode simplesmente remover o `DATE()`, dessa forma ficaria:

```
partida.data_hora >= now()
```

Isso iria fazer com que comparasse também o `01:02:03`, assim atingindo o que deseja.

Por exemplo:

Utilizando sem o `date()`, a solução:

```
SELECT '2017-01-02 01:02:03' >= '2017-01-02 01:02:01'
// Resposta: 1

SELECT '2017-01-02 01:02:03' >= '2017-01-02 01:02:04'
// Resposta: 0
```

Enquanto que usando `date()`:

```
SELECT DATE('2017-01-02 01:02:03') >= DATE('2017-01-02 01:02:01')
// Resposta: 1

SELECT DATE('2017-01-02 01:02:03') >= DATE('2017-01-02 01:02:04')
// Resposta: 1
```

**Extra:**

Se eu compreendi corretamente o SQL, quando você usa o `>= now()` não faz sentido usar o `(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(now(), partida.data_hora)) > 600`, isso seria redundante.

Você poderia substituir:

```
(date(partida.data_hora) >= date(now()) AND (TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(now(), partida.data_hora)) > 600))
```

Por:

```
(partida.data_hora >= (now() + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE))
```

Isso iria garantir que obrigatoriamente o `partida.data_hora` seja maior do que a data atual somado com 10 minutos, o que iria resolver os dois problemas.